# Angularjs adding html to variable with ui-sref link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following code that adds html to a variable. However, when it get's shown on the page, the link doesn't work.

What's the best way to get a `ui-sref` link to work when inserting it dynamically?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
.controller('page', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $state, $sce) {

    $scope.message = $sce.trustAsHtml('A <a ui-sref="login">login</a> link');

})
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-bind-html="message"></div>
```

Comment: Probably have to use `$compile` - `$sce.trustAsHtml($compile('A <a ui-sref="login">login</a> link')($scope));`

Comment: Why are you trying to add it dynamically?  Can you not just put it in the template/html file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bsq7P9nDL46c3FwXsmBN?p=preview)

I would say, that we can use combination of:

- **`$state.href()`** *(doc [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state))* and
- **`ng-href`** *(doc [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref))*

*(but only in case, if the params passed are part of url)*

This would be the result

```
<a ng-href="{{$state.href(myStateName, myParams)}}">
```

And now *(in [the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bsq7P9nDL46c3FwXsmBN?p=preview))* we can change **myStateName** into `parent`, `parent.child`, `home` and it will change properly the generated href:

```
<input ng-model="myStateName" />
<input ng-model="myParams.param" />
```

Because these are states in plunker

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
      url: "/home",
      ...
  })
  .state('parent', {
      url: "/parent?param",
      ...
  })
  .state('parent.child', { 
      url: "/child",
      ...
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bsq7P9nDL46c3FwXsmBN?p=preview)