# AngularJS : Pass in ui-router state parameter to expression

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to pass in a parameter to `ui-sref` using UI-Router. Usually it would be something like:

```
ui-sref="example.state({param: value})"
```

However, in my controller I set the routes in an array of objects like:

```
self.dynamicId = $stateParams.id;

self.menu = [
  {
    label: 'Example1',
    route: 'example.state1',
    stateName: 'state1'
  },
  {
    label: 'Example2',
    route: 'example.state2',
    stateName: 'state2'
  }
];
```

How do I pass in the `dynamicId` parameter using an Angular expression in my template?

```
<div ng-repeat="link in menu">
    <a ui-sref="{{ link.route }}"></a>
</div>
```

Right now I'm hardcoding the state name, which sort of defeats the purpose of using `ui-sref`:

```
<a ui-sref="example.{{stateName}}({id: dynamicId})"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say, that similar issue is discussed here

#### [Angularjs adding html to variable with ui-sref link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30058287/1679310)

In a nutshell *(check [the working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bsq7P9nDL46c3FwXsmBN?p=preview))* - we can use combination of the natural `Angular` and `UI-Router` features:

- **`ng-href`** *(doc [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref))*
- **`$state.href()`** *(doc [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state))* and

NOTE: This would work for params defined as part of **url** *(not just `params : {}` - without url representation)*

The link would look like this:

```
<a ng-href="{{$state.href(myStateName, myParams)}}">
```

I'd recommend to play with [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bsq7P9nDL46c3FwXsmBN?p=preview), to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible right now. Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/395). One solution would be to precalculate the url with `stateName` and `dynamicId` using [`$state.href`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statehrefstateorname--params--options) if this is possible in your scenario.