# Dynamic ui-sref in directive template Angular Js

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

In my angular js Application, I have a directive inside a ng-repeat. Directive has a template in which the HTML part is loaded. Inside that template I am declaring a ui-sref Router dynamically setting states!

This does not Work!

I have tried a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LqXrC/92/)

Without using a Directive ui-sref [works](http://jsfiddle.net/LqXrC/91/) Fine. But I need it in Directive's template.

**MY HTML PART**

```
<div ng-repeat="sp in obj.PEs">
  <div draw-pe proc="{{sp.peId}}"></div>
</div>

<div style="border:1px;" ui-view="properties"></div>
```

**My Script Part**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router"]);
myApp.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.obj = {
    "PEs": {
      "1": {
        "peId": "1",
        "peName": "Exp1",
        "peDisplayName": "Exp",
        "peType": "Exp",
        "peCategory": "PE"
      },
      "2": {
        "peId": "2",
        "peName": "RN1",
        "peDisplayName": "RNull",
        "peType": "RN",
        "peCategory": "PE"
      }
    }
  }
})

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
    .state('Exp', {
      url: '/Exp/:peId',
      views: {
        "properties": {
          template: ".<h3>I am Exp ! </h3>",
          controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
            var peId = $stateParams.peId;
            alert("Peid-> " + angular.toJson($scope.obj.PEs[peId]));

          }
        }
      }
    })
    .state('RN', {
      url: '/RN/:peId',
      views: {
        "properties": {
          template: "<h3> I am RN ! </h3>",
          controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
            var peId = $stateParams.peId;
            alert("Peid-> " + angular.toJson($scope.obj.PEs[peId]));
          }
        }
      }
    })
});
myApp.directive("drawPe", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    template: '<div ui-sref="{{peObj.peType}}( { peId:peObj.peId } )"> <h5>{{peObj.peDisplayName}}</h5></div>',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      var procId = $scope.$eval(attrs.proc);
      alert(procId);
      // alert(angular.toJson(scope.obj.processElements[procId]))
      $scope.peObj = $scope.obj.PEs[procId];
    }
  }
})
```

See the Browser Console, on clicking the output Part!

**ERROR**

> Error: Invalid state ref '( { peId:peObj.peId } )'

What will be the best Practice to call dynamic state names inside directives Template?  I Have read some previous asked question and answer, But I am not clear with the idea as I am new to Angular Js.

Any Idea/help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically set the value of ui-sref Angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349731/dynamically-set-the-value-of-ui-sref-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $compile service to compile your directive's template when your scope changes.

Your directive could look like this:

```
myApp.directive("drawPe", function($compile) {

return {
 restrict: "AE",
 tranclude: true,
 scope: {
   peObj: '='
 },
 template: '<a href="" ui-sref="{{peObj.peType}} ({peId: peObj.peId})"> <h5>{{peObj.peDisplayName}}</h5></a>',
 link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  console.log(scope.peObj);
  scope.$watch(
    function(scope) {
      // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
      //return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
    },
    function(value) {
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
  );
  }
 }
 });
```

And your html:

```
<div ng-repeat="sp in obj.PEs">
  <div draw-pe pe-obj="sp" proc="{{sp.peId}}"></div>
</div>

<div style="border:1px;" ui-view="properties"></div>
```

Working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/feyyazakkus/xkm9txaf/1/).

Comment: I need to bind the rootscope obj in peObj in link, I couldn't able to access obj, because the scope is changed? what should we do to make obj variable accessible in link function?  console.log(scope.obj); -> this gives undefined

Comment: You can assign your 'obj' variable to $rootScope instead of $scope. Then use it in directive like: myApp.directive("drawPe", function($rootScope) { return { link: function(...) { console.log($rootScope.obj) } });

Comment: Actually It is working in fiddle but not in my application. My rootScope variable not accessible in drawPe directive. getting undefined.

Comment: Did you define $rootScope in your controller as dependency? Your controller should start like: myApp.controller("testCtrl", function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.obj = {.....

Comment: Thank you for your Wonderful help ! But without $watch only if we compile $compile(element.contents())(scope);  my problem got solved! Thanks man !