# UI-Router's ui-sref creating wrong href

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a SPA with 2 ui-views: header and body. The header is run by one controller, and the controllers that handle the body (depending on the state) make a call to a service function I created as follows:

```
    /**
     * Sets the header bar's attributes
     *
     * @param inverse bool Whether the color scheme should be inverted
     * @param button bool Whether the back button should be presented
     * @param link string The route the back button will take the user to when pressed
     * @param title string The translation key to use for the title to be shown in the headerbar
     * @param data string Characters to be inserted in the span next to the title
     *
     **/
    return {
        set: function(inverse, button, link, title, data) {
            // set defaults
            inverse = typeof inverse !== 'undefined' ? inverse : false;
            button = typeof button !== 'undefined' ? button : false;
            link = typeof link !== 'undefined' ? link : $state.current.name;
            title = typeof title !== 'undefined' ? title : undefined;
            data = typeof data !== 'undefined' ? data : false;
            // store for HeaderController to retrieve
            $localStorage.headerInverse = inverse;
            $localStorage.headerBackButton = button;
            $localStorage.headerBackLink = link;
            $localStorage.headerTitle = title;
            $localStorage.headerData = data;

            broadcast.announce('setHeader');
        }
    };
```

Like so:

```
    header.set(true, true, 'app.search1', 'MY_PROFILE');
```

The header's controller listens to the broadcast with:

```
    broadcast.listenFor('setHeader', function() {
        vm.headerTitle = $localStorage.headerTitle; // expects the translation key to look up
        vm.headerData = $localStorage.headerData;
        vm.headerInverse = $localStorage.headerInverse;
        vm.headerBackLink = $localStorage.headerBackLink;
        vm.headerBackButton = $localStorage.headerBackButton;
        vm.headerMoreIcon = $localStorage.headerMoreIcon;
    });
```

And the header's html has:

```
    <a ui-sref="{{ vm.headerBackLink }}"></a>
```

So what I would expect is:

```
    <a href="#/search1" ui-sref="app.search1"></a>
```

Yet what I'm getting rendered is:

```
    <a href="#/profile" ui-sref="app.search1"></a>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349731/dynamically-set-the-value-of-ui-sref-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing state name dynamically, try this:

```
$scope.getLinkUrl = function(){
  return $state.href('state-name', {someParam: $scope.someValue});
};
```

---

```
 <a ng-href="{{getLinkUrl()}}">Dynamic Link</a>
```

Ref: [Dynamically set the value of ui-sref Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349731/dynamically-set-the-value-of-ui-sref-angularjs)

Comment: Thank you so much! Never would've thought to check the validity of dynamically passing the state name to ui-sref.

Cheers!