# How to navigate one page to another page with $scope value parameter in data-ui-sref in Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular js for the web application. So I want to navigate one page to another page with some parameter in data-ui-sref. When I use static parameter then it will navigate with parameter.

**Example:**
`<a data-ui-sref="app.admin({startFrom:'param1',endTo:'param2'})">click</a>`

**Module.js**

```
    .state('app.admin', {
        url: '/travlers?startFrom&endTo',
        data: {
          title: 'travelers'
        },
        params :
        {
           startFrom: null,
           endTo:null

         },
       views: {
      "content@app": {
        templateUrl: 'app/admin.html',
        controller: 'admin'
      }
    }
    });
```

If I used static parameter in data-ui-sref then it will work. But If I take from scope value in parameter then it is not working.

**When I use scope value in data-ui-sref parameter**

**example.html**

```
 <a data-ui-sref="app.admin({startFrom:'{{dateFrom}}',endTo:'{{dateTo}}'})">click</a>
```

**example.js**

```
angular.module('app.admin').controller('example', function () {
      $scope.dateFrom="07-05-17";
      $scope.dateTo="07-05-17"
});
```

When I see in console then scope value is append in **data-ui-sref** parameter

**When I see in console then it is looks like this**

```
<a data-ui-sref="app.systemAdmin.travelers({startFrom:'07-05-17',endTo:'07-05-17'})" class="fa fa-external-link-square" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:18px;color:#fff" href="#/systemadmin/travlers">click</a>
```

After click the link then parameter is not going to module.js. URL is form without parameter and parameter(dateFrom,dateTo) is not going in **state url**.
I have seen one link. But it is for dynamic value [Dynamically set the value of ui-sref Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349731/dynamically-set-the-value-of-ui-sref-angularjs) but my query is not for scope value in as parameter in data-ui-sref.

Comment: ui-sref value is a scope expression. Therefore, you don't have to interpolate the scope value but pass it as if it was javascript with direct access to your scope like: `<a data-ui-sref="app.admin({ startFrom: dateFrom, endTo: dateTo })">click</a>`.

Comment: @Lenilson. It is working Thanks a lot

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro. Please give into answer for help to others

Comment: @VSH do you realise that my answer already told you to do the exact same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ui-sref`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref) value is a scope expression. Therefore, you don't have to interpolate the scope value but pass it as if it was javascript with direct access to your scope like: `<a data-ui-sref="app.admin({ startFrom: dateFrom, endTo: dateTo })">click</a>`.

Comment: Can hide the parameter from url But it should exist?

Comment: @VSH according to [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls), it doesn't require it to exist.